# @BeforeClass doesn't run at all in IntelliJ

Tags: testng

i have this code written:

```
  UserManager userManager = new UserManager(); 

    @BeforeClass
    public static void tryi (){
        System.out.println("WooooooHOOOO");
    }

    @BeforeMethod 
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("zdravo"); 
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true) //AfterClass se izvrshuva samo ednash za ovaa klasa na kraj a ne posle sekoj @Test
   
        System.out.println("cao");
    }


    @Test(description = " Verify that addUSer method returns true when successful")
    public void aTest1() {
        System.out.println("This is test 1");
    }

    @Test(timeOut = 500) // not enough time - will fail
    public void cTest2() {
        System.out.println("This is test 2");
    }

    @Test(enabled = false)
   nad class vazi za site testovi
    public void bTest3() {
        System.out.println("This is test 3");
    }


    @Test(priority = 1) //davame prioritet prv da se izvrshi
    public void successfulAddUserReturnsTrue() {
        //Arrange
        // UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
        //Act
        boolean result = userManager.addUser("john@email.com");
        //Assert
        Assert.assertTrue(result); 
    }

    @Test
    public void getUserReturnsExistingSavedUser() {
        //Arrange
        //UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
        userManager.addUser("john@email.com");
        //Act
        String user = userManager.getUser("john@email.com");
        //Assert
        Assert.assertEquals(user, "john@email.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void getNonExistingUserReturnsNull() {
        //Arrange
        //UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
        //Act
        String user = userManager.getUser("john@email.com");
        //Assert
        Assert.assertNull(user, "The method should return null if it doesn't find a user");
    }
}
```

and now when I run the test, everything is OK except the @BeforeClass does'n run and it doesnt show in the console.

here is the response i get:

```
zdravo
This is test 1
cao
zdravo
This is test 2
cao
zdravo
cao
zdravo
cao
zdravo
cao
```

## ===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 5, Passes: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it by adding this import:

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod